# Web scraping in r with rvest: if div is missing return NA

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a tooltip for four divs: shoot-type, blow-type, time, and shoot-xg. Occasionally one of the divs is missing. For example, [2] below does not have a "tooltip-shoot-xg" div.

How would I cycle through the div.tooltip and return a NA if any of the four components are missing?

```
[1] "<div class=\"tooltip\" style=\"left: 37.5%; top: 36.5789%;\">\n<div class=\"tooltip-title\">\n<div class=\"tooltip-shoot-type\">Shot blocked</div>\n<div class=\"tooltip-blow-type\">Smith </div>\n<div class=\"tooltip-shoot-name\"></div>\n</div>\n<div class=\"tooltip-time\">a </div>\n<div class=\"tooltip-time\">Half 1, 09:18 28/01/18</div>\n<div class=\"tooltip-shoot-xg\">Expected goals: 0.09</div>\n</div>"

[2] "<div class=\"tooltip\" style=\"left: 54.7059%; top: 11.0526%;\">\n<div class=\"tooltip-title\">\n<div class=\"tooltip-shoot-type\">Own goal</div>\n<div class=\"tooltip-blow-type\">Johnson </div>\n<div class=\"tooltip-shoot-name\"></div>\n</div>\n<div class=\"tooltip-time\">h </div>\n<div class=\"tooltip-time\">Half 1, 14:36 28/01/18</div>\n</div>"
```

The above is the result of

```
pg %>% 
  html_nodes("div.tooltip")
```

Comment: Can you share the link from where you are scraping this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use XPath selector, a dot (`.`) presents the current node and you can find sub divs relatively from it. In this example, the code looks like this:

```
divs <- pg %>% html_nodes("div.tooltip")
for (i in 1:length(divs)){
  shoot-type <- divs[i] %>% html_node(xpath = "./div[@class='tooltip-shoot-type']") %>% html_text()
  blow-type <- divs[i] %>% html_node(xpath = "./div[@class='tooltip-blow-type']") %>% html_text()
  time <- divs[i] %>% html_node(xpath = "./div[@class='tooltip-time']") %>% html_text()
  shoot-xg <- divs[i] %>% html_node(xpath = "./div[@class='tooltip-shoot-xg']") %>% html_text()
  # add code here to save data
}
```

Then if there's not `tooltip-shoot-xg` class div in the node, `shoot-xg` will return NA.

Comment: Thanks! I think the issue you clarified the most for me was how to use html_node() to look for a specific tag. I've been using html_nodes() to quickly grab everything - which works great unless there is a missing tag. Thanks again!